# Fabric.js replace color in an Image object

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs

I am a fair beginner to fabric.js and wanted to know if there was any way that I could replace a specific color in a Fabric.js Image object with another one. I know about the Blend & RemoveColor filters but those don't do the whole job.

For example if I have an image of a rainbow -
[image: Original Image]

now I want to replace a specified color (red in this case) with another specified color (blue in this case) and want this as a result -

[image: Desired result]

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: Please, only add relevant tags. It doesn't seem like a React question.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros apologies, I am currently working on a react project with fabric.js so I must have added it by mistake

Comment: No worries, I've removed it already :) Hopefully, you'll receive an answer to your question soon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fabric.js manipulate Image object pixel by pixel to change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65608195/fabric-js-manipulate-image-object-pixel-by-pixel-to-change-color)  I left an answer on that one that seems to cover both of these.